# ajax response of success function not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, json.net, asp.net-ajax

I creates an Popup in asp.net core application to create and edit new customer by using ajax but when post the data, i get this error :

> {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ,
> setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
>
> abort: ƒ ( statusText ) always: ƒ () catch: ƒ ( fn ) done: ƒ () fail:
> ƒ () getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ () getResponseHeader: ƒ ( key )
> overrideMimeType: ƒ ( type ) pipe: ƒ ( /* fnDone, fnFail, fnProgress
> */ ) progress: ƒ () promise: ƒ ( obj ) readyState: 4 responseText: "{"isValid":true,"html":{" setRequestHeader: ƒ ( name, value ) state:
> ƒ () status: 200 statusCode: ƒ ( map ) statusText: "parsererror" then:
> ƒ ( onFulfilled, onRejected, onProgress )
> **proto**: Object

﻿
​
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgyAs.png)

this my function in my controller

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate(int id = 0)
    {
        if (id == 0)
            return View(new Customer());
        else
        {
            var CustomerModel = _customerRepository.Find(id);
            if (CustomerModel == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return View(CustomerModel);
        }
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult CreateOrUpdate(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Insert
            if (customer.CustomerId == 0)
            {
                 _customerRepository.Create(customer);

            }
            //Update
            else
            {
               
                    _customerRepository.Update(customer);
             
            }
            return Json(new { isValid = true, html = GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "_ViewAllCustomer", _customerRepository.GetAll()) });
        }


        return Json(new { isValid = false, html = GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString(this, "CreateOrUpdate", customer) });
    }
```

this my ajax method in site.js

```js
PostCustomer = form => {
 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: form.action,
            data: new FormData(form),
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.isValid) {
                    $('#view-all-customer').html(result.html)
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html('');
                    $('#form-modal .modal-title').html('');
                    $('#form-modal').modal('hide');
                }
                else
                    $('#form-modal .modal-body').html(result.html);
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        })
        return false;
    
    }
```

this is my view CreateOrUpdate.cshtml

```html
@model Library.Models.Customer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create New Customer";
    Layout = null;
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <form asp-controller="Customer" asp-action="CreateOrUpdate" asp-route-id="@Model.CustomerId" onsubmit="return PostCustomer(this);">

            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.CustomerId" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="btn-group col-md-12">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary center-block" />
                    </div>
                </div>
</form>
    </div>
</div>


@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

can anyone help me please :( ?

Comment: `'parsererror"` means the json response is invalid and can't be processed by JSON.parse(). Inspect the actual request body in browser dev tools network and see what exactly gets returned

Comment: As mentioned in the above comment, the error should be related to the json you return. Please provide a detailed `GlobalClass.RenderRazorViewToString` method.